# importing Chinese characters into sqlite database

Tags: character-encoding, sqlite

how do i import chinese text into an sqlite database?
I have used Google translate to generate all my android applications text, then saved in open office calc csv file.
the csv file shows all the chinese characters correctly
when i come to import this data i end up with ? instead of the chinese characters. I've tried using Sqlite database browser 2.0, sqlite adim, and sqlite manager. I still cannot import the complete text as i see them displayed in Google Translate.
what sqlite tool/utility and character set combination actually works and imports all chinese characters without ? appearing?

Comment: SQLite is UTF-8 internally (I have quite a bit of code that relies on this), but somewhere along the way things are going wrong. I'd guess either the import to the DB — how _exactly_ are you doing that — or the extract; the latter case would mean that the database is correct, but when querying things are being messed up. I'm suspicious of those tools…

Comment: both sqlite browser and sqlite adim have import functions... if i execute a simple sql insert in sqlbrowser it works fine. i have almost 700 inserts to perform, i do not want to have to code 700 individual inserts. surely there must be a sqlite utility that can import chinese text

Comment: Ensure that the .csv file is encoded as UTF-8. Do you know the encoding of your files?

Comment: CL - i wasnt using UTF8 files, that was my problem. i am now using Notepad++ and able to save Korean and Chinese characters.